# expected batch_size() is not the same as target batch_size() pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, training-data, batchsize

I wrote a code to segment a satellite-picture into seven regions (city, forest, water, ...).
The problem is that when I execute the script I get exact the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/.../pytorch_test.py", line 215, in 
> model = train_model(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, num_epochs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/.../pytorch_test.py", line 179, in train_model
> train_loss = train(model, train_dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer, device)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/.../pytorch_test.py", line 134, in train
> loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 1174, in forward
> return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 3029, in cross_entropy
> return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ValueError: Expected input batch_size (3) to match target batch_size (9).

The problem is that when I change the batch_size I get every time tripple the target batch_size, but I cannot find the bug. I felt I searched the whole internet, but found nothing.
I hope some of you can help me!

Thats my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from PIL import Image
import os
from PIL import ImageEnhance

class SatelliteDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_folder, label_folder, transform=None):
        self.image_folder = image_folder
        self.label_folder = label_folder
        self.transform = transform

        self.image_paths = sorted([os.path.join(image_folder, filename) for filename in os.listdir(image_folder)])
        self.label_paths = sorted([os.path.join(label_folder, filename) for filename in os.listdir(label_folder)])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image_path = self.image_paths[idx]
        label_path = self.label_paths[idx]

        image = Image.open(image_path)
        label = Image.open(label_path)

        image = self.adjust_brightness(image, brightness_factor=1.8)

        # Resize images to 512x512
        image = image.resize((512, 512), Image.BILINEAR)
        label = label.resize((512, 512), Image.NEAREST)

        # Apply transformations if specified
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
            label = self.transform(label)

        return image, label

    def adjust_brightness(self, image, brightness_factor=1.0):
        enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(image)
        enhanced_image = enhancer.enhance(brightness_factor)
        return enhanced_image


# Define paths to the folders containing satellite images and corresponding labels
image_folder = "/Users/.../train_data/images"
label_folder = "/Users/.../train_data/masks"

# Define transformations for normalization and scaling
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]),
])

# Create an instance of the SatelliteDataset
dataset = SatelliteDataset(image_folder, label_folder, transform=transform)

# Create DataLoader for training
def collate_fn(batch):
    images, labels = zip(*batch)
    images = torch.stack(images)
    labels = torch.stack(labels)
    return images, labels

batch_size = 3
train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, collate_fn=collate_fn)

# cnn
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()

        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(512, out_channels=7, kernel_size=1, stride=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.maxpool1(x)

        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.maxpool2(x)

        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.maxpool3(x)

        x = self.conv4(x)
        x = self.relu4(x)

        x = self.conv5(x)

        x = torch.softmax(x, dim=1)  # add Softmax layer
        return x


# Training loop
def train(model, dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer, device):
    model.train()  # Set the model to training mode

    running_loss = 0.0

    for images, labels in dataloader:
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(images)

        # Reshape labels dimensions
        labels = labels.view(-1, 512, 512)
        labels = labels.long()

        # Calculate loss
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)

        # Backward pass and weight update
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item() * images.size(0)

    epoch_loss = running_loss / len(dataloader.dataset)

    return epoch_loss


# Validation
def evaluate(model, dataloader, loss_fn, device):
    model.eval()  # Set the model to evaluation mode

    running_loss = 0.0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, labels in dataloader:
            images = images.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)

            # Forward pass
            outputs = model(images)

            # Calculate loss
            loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)

            running_loss += loss.item() * images.size(0)

    epoch_loss = running_loss / len(dataloader.dataset)
    return epoch_loss


# Perform training
def train_model(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, num_epochs):
    best_val_loss = float('inf')
    best_model_weights = None
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}")

        # Training step
        train_loss = train(model, train_dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer, device)
        print(f"Train Loss: {train_loss}")

        # Validation step
        val_loss = evaluate(model, val_dataloader, loss_fn, device)
        print(f"Val Loss: {val_loss}")

        # Check for improvement in validation loss
        if val_loss < best_val_loss:
            best_val_loss = val_loss
            best_model_weights = model.state_dict()

    # Return the best model
    model.load_state_dict(best_model_weights)
    return model



# Example usage of the model
model = CNN(in_channels=3, out_channels=7)

# Select device (CPU)
device = torch.device("cpu")

# Loss function
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)

Number of epochs (adjust as needed)
num_epochs = 10

# Create a separate DataLoader for validation with batch_size=3
val_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, collate_fn=collate_fn)

# Perform training
model = train_model(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, num_epochs)
```

By the way I am programming on MacOS and with VSC

**I tried:**
I copied all the error messages into google and read almost every article on that problem.
Nonetheless I could not resolve this. I tried to change the batch sizes (I have 804 pictures to train the model with) and changed the data-loader.
I also asked ChatGPT, although it explained the problem very good and gave a couple of ideas to solve this, it helped not.

Comment: This is not related to your specific issue. But you are using a softmax at the end of your CNN, but your loss_fn CrossEntropy() expects pre-softmax logits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a line `labels = labels.view(-1, 512, 512)` that is changing the dimensions of your labels. From your dataloader, it seems that your labels are images. If it had 3 channels (RGB), then this dimension-changing line would basically triple your batch size.

Comment: Thanks, the error message does not appear anymore after i deleted the         labels = labels.view(-1, 512, 512) and labels = labels.long().
I deleted also the softmax.
But now there is another issue that i get, I get the now the error message that:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../DeepGlobe_Land_Classification_Dataset/train_data/pytorch_test.py", line 210, in <module>
    model = train_model(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, num_epochs) 
RuntimeError: only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of dimension: 4

Comment: Im sorry, im just a beginner. Maybe you can also help me with that problem? Im trying to segment pictures into 7 regions.
thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I think your labels are now of shape `(batch size, 3, height, width)` but it should be `(batch size, height, width)` for segmentation. You should figure out how to convert your data to this format. Also, if the answer is correct, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick symbol.

Comment: than you very much! I appreciate your help!!!